# Copying an sql file into a different database on Raspberry Pi

Tags: mysql, linux, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I have a file called "mysql.sql".

I have installed mysql on Raspberry Pi, and I need to create the same tables in "mysql.sql".

How can I manage to copy "mysql.sql" file directly into my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'mysql.sql' INTO TABLE tbl_name
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

If it's table content.

[Ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html)

---

Or:

```
mysql -u username -p databaseName < mysql.sql
```

If it's a database dump

[Ref](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.0/en/reloading-sql-format-dumps.html)

Answer (score 1):

Using [input redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

```
mysql -u username -ppassword < mysql.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

**mysql.sql** is a dump file?

If yes you can import on 2 steps;

```
# echo "create database databasename" | mysql -u user -ppassword
```

and than

```
# mysql -u user -ppassword databasename < mysql.sql
```

Comment: Mario thank you for your answer, but instead of "mysql.sql", I enter home/pi/attandance-master/mysql.sql, it does nothing, it goes the the next line, but does nothing.

Comment: add simicolon at the end like :  mysql -u user -ppassword databasename < mysql.sql;